# Decoding pickle file

Tags: python, arrays, scikit-learn, decode

I have a pickle file which I am trying to open.  I am using python3.

```
import pickle
from sklearn import preprocessing
le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
age = pickle.loads(open('/home/ubuntu/Downloads/agele.cpickle','rb').read()
```

The last line provides me with a warning:

```
usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sklearn/base.py:251: UserWarning: Trying to unpickle estimator LabelEncoder from version 0.18 when using version 0.20.1. This might lead to breaking code or invalid results. Use at your own risk.
  UserWarning)

age.classes_
```

prints an array as follows:

```
array([b'0_2', b'15_20', b'25_32', b'38_43', b'48_53', b'4_6', b'60_inf',
       b'8_13'], dtype='|S6')
```

I am trying to extract values from this array.  The following were the subsequent errors i am getting.

```
le.inverse_transform(age)

sklearn.exceptions.NotFittedError: This LabelEncoder instance is not fitted yet. Call 'fit' with appropriate arguments before using this method.
ag=le.fit_transform(age)
ValueError: bad input shape ()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The array values are utf-8 encoded bytes 
To extract values from the array you could try something like this ;

```
age_classes = []
for i in age.classes_ :
    age_classes.append(i.decode('utf-8'))
```

It worked for me and I got this as output : 
[image: this is after printing the new list created]

Comment: thank you..this worked....i was trying in the following lines:  `a=age.classes_; a=a.tolist(); for i in a: print(i)`....but still couldnt fit the decode parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Notice, this is a warning from `sklearn` and not from pickle.

There were a few breaking changes in version `0.20.1`, which means it is not backwards compatible with some other versions.

This error is letting you know that the object you are loading is from an older version, which means it might not be compatible with the version you are running.

you can read the [changelog](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/whats_new.html#version-0-20-1) and see what changed.